# Computing cov of 2 binomial random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

we drop a normal cube 20 times.
X - is the number of even values
Y - is the number of times the cube landed on 3.

As much as I understand:
$$X\sim B(20, \frac{1}{2}) \\Y \sim B(20, \frac{1}{6} )$$
How can I compute $E[XY]$?

Comment: Hint: Write X and Y each as a sum of 20 random variables with obvious dependencies then deduce E(XY).

Comment: It has too many combinations possible

Comment: No. Please explain what is stopping you.

Comment: 400 combinations possible, I dont see how its possible, if you can be more specific please.

Comment: Sure. Lots of them are of the same type hence they contribute for the same amount. But first, to see this, one has to write X as a sum of 20 elementary random variables and Y as a sum of 20 elementary random variables. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_k$ be the number of even numbers appearing on the $k$th trial, so that
$$
X_k=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability }1/2, \\ 0 & \text{with probability }1/2. \end{cases}
$$
Let $Y_k$ be the number of $3$s appearing on the $k$th trial, so that
$$
Y_k=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability }1/6, \\ 0 & \text{with probability }5/6. \end{cases}
$$
Then $X_kY_k$ is always $0$, since one always gets either a non-even number or a non-$3$.  So
$$
\operatorname{cov}(X_k, Y_k) = \mathbb E(X_k Y_k) - \mathbb E(X_k)\mathbb E(Y_k) = 0 - \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 1 6 = -\frac{1}{12}.
$$

Since the $20$ trials are independent, we have
$$
\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=\operatorname{cov}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{20}X_k, \sum_{k=1}^{20} Y_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{20} \operatorname{cov}(X_k , Y_k) = 20\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{12}\right).
$$
So
$$
\frac{-5}{3}=\frac{-20}{12}=\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb E(XY) - \mathbb E(X)\mathbb E(Y) = \mathbb E(XY) - 10\cdot\frac{20}{6}.
$$
From that you can deduce $\mathbb E(XY)$.  But if your purpose is just to find $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$, I'd do it the way I did it above rather than by any method that relies on finding $\mathbb E(XY)$.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

Let $Z = (1,2,3,4,5,6)$ denote the sides of the cube (die).

**For a sample of size $n=1$:**

- If $Z=1$, then:  $(X=0, Y=0)$
- If $Z=2$, then:  $(X=1, Y=0)$
- If $Z=3$, then:  $(X=0, Y=1)$
- If $Z=4$, then:  $(X=1, Y=0)$
- If $Z=5$, then:  $(X=0, Y=0)$
- If $Z=6$, then:  $(X=1, Y=0)$

Note that there are only 3 possible $(X,Y)$ outcomes. In summary, given a sample of size $n=1$, the joint pmf of $(X,Y)$, say $f(x,y)$, is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/dicemicejointpmf.png))</sub>

Here are two alternative ways of proceeding, for any general number of draws $n$:

## Method 1: Moments of moments

Let $(X_1, Y_1), \dots, (X_n,Y_n))$ denote a sample of size $n$ (i.e. $n$ throws). Using power sum notation, let $s_{r,t}=\sum _{i=1}^n X_i^r Y_i^t$. Then, our problem is to find:

$$E\big[{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} {\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i} \big] = E\big[s_{1,0} s_{0,1}\big]$$

This is just a *moments of moments* problem. In particular, we seek the 1st Raw Moment of $(s_{1,0} s_{0,1})$, and the solution is immediately given by:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/dicemomentum.png))</sub>

for *any* distribution whose moments exist, where I am using the `RawMomentToRaw` function from the *mathStatica* software package. The solution is expressed in terms of the raw product moments of the population $\acute{\mu}_{r,s}=E\left[X^r Y^s\right]$. In the case of our joint pmf $f(x,y)$ given above, the solution is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/dicemomentsofmoments.png))</sub>

... or manually:  $\acute{\mu}_{1,0}=E\left[X \right] = \frac12$, and $\acute{\mu}_{0,1}=E\left[Y \right] = \frac16$, and $\acute{\mu}_{1,1}=E\left[X Y\right] = 0$, and substitute into `sol` to yield:  $\frac{1}{12} n (n-1)$.

## Method 2: pgf method

Given joint pmf $f(x,y)$ above, the bivariate probability generating function (pgf) $E[t_1^X t_2^Y]$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/dicebivariatepgf.png))</sub>

where I am using the `Expect` function from *mathStatica* to automate (but easy enough by hand too).

**For a sample of size $n$:**

Consider now a sample of size $n$. The joint variables of interest are now: $(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)$. Then, the bivariate pgf for the sum $S$, given $n$ throws, is:

$$\begin{align*}\displaystyle \text{pgfS} &=  E\big[t_1^{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} t_2^{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}\big] 
\\&=  E\big[(t_1^{X_1} t_2^{Y_1}) (t_1^{X_2} t_2^{Y_2})  \dots  (t_1^{X_n} t_2^{Y_n})\big]  
\\&=  E\big[t_1^{X_1} t_2^{Y_1} \big] E\big[t_1^{X_2} t_2^{Y_2} \big] \times \dots \times E\big[t_1^{X_n} t_2^{Y_n} \big]  \quad \quad \text{          (since } (X_i,Y_i) \text{ is independent of } (X_j,Y_j) )
\\ &= 6^{-n} (2 + 3t_1 + t_2)^n \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{(by identicality) }\end{align*}$$

We can use the pgf as a factorial moment generating function which provides an immediate solution, namely that:

$$E\big[{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} {\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i} \big] = \frac{\partial ^{2} pgfS}{\partial t_1 \partial t_2}|_{\overset{\rightharpoonup }{t}=\overset{\rightharpoonup }{1}} = \frac{1}{12} n (n-1)$$

In the case of $n = 20$, the answer is thus:  $\frac{95}{3}$.

**Notes**

1. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors of the software used above.